# "Run-time error '1004'. Application-defined or operation-defined error" with row to column autofill VBA

Tags: excel, vba

[Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bm8p.png) *How I receive the report*. 
[Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8R1c.png) *How I would like the final outcome to look like*.

I keep getting Run-time error '1004'. Application-defined or operation-defined error any suggestions?

```
Sub Row2Column()
Dim rngData As Range, r As Range, myDate As Date, strName As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   With Worksheets("Sheet0")
    .Columns("A:B").Insert
    Set rngData = .Columns("D").SpecialCells(2)
    For Each r In rngData.Areas
        myDate = r(1, 1).Value
        strName = r(3, 1).Value
        r.Offset(3, -3).Resize(r.Rows.Count - 3, 1).Value = strName
        r.Offset(3, -2).Resize(r.Rows.Count - 3, 1).Value = myDate
    Next r
     .Columns("A:B").AutoFit
   End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: There are at least a hundred previous questions with the same error message here, most of which have answers. I find it difficult to believe you read all of them and couldn't find a solution to this problem, since it's the same solution in almost all of them.

Comment: There were 0 when I looked for the source of my problem, that matched what could help me. Thats why I posted it, to learn from it. Not to have some guy with magic wand issues who wants to gig a guy for a problem he needed solved because he understood the concepts of other posts. Thanks for your input....

Answer (score 0):

Try the following piece of code:

```
Sub Row2Column()

Dim rngData As Range, r As Range, myDate As Date, strName As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
     .Columns("A:B").Insert

    ' *** this is the only modification I made ****
     Set rngData = .Columns("D:D").SpecialCells(2)
     For Each r In rngData.Areas
         myDate = r(1, 1).Value
         strName = r(3, 1).Value
         r.Offset(3, -3).Resize(r.Rows.Count - 3, 1).Value = strName
         r.Offset(3, -2).Resize(r.Rows.Count - 3, 1).Value = myDate
     Next r
      .Columns("A:B").AutoFit
    End With
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Run time error can be removed by changing the following lines

```
 myDate = r(1, 1).Value
 strName = r(3, 1).Value
```

**to**

```
 myDate = .Cells(1, 1).Value
 strName = .Cells(3, 1).Value
```

**EDIT DATED 02-06-2016(IST)**

Please refer your comments yesterday that informed that changes are still giving problem. I have rerun the program after preparing sample data.

Here is the code used by me exactly as per my previous answer except that drive and file paths were adjusted to suit to my computer.

```
Sub Row2Column()
Dim rngData As Range, r As Range, myDate As Date, strName As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Columns("A:B").Insert
    Set rngData = .Columns("D").SpecialCells(2)
    For Each r In rngData.Areas
        myDate = .Cells(1, 1).Value
        strName = .Cells(3, 1).Value
        r.Offset(3, -3).Resize(r.Rows.Count - 3, 1).Value = strName
        r.Offset(3, -2).Resize(r.Rows.Count - 3, 1).Value = myDate
    Next r
     .Columns("A:B").AutoFit
   End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Sample data before and after program run is shown in the snapshot. It ran smoothly without any error on my computer.

[image: before program run]

[image: after program run]

**REMARKS**
Now let me explain why are you getting the problem.If we refer to MSDN Documenation [Range.Cells Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx)

It mentions examples of correct syntax of usage. Typical example is

```
Set r = Range("myRange") 
For n = 1 To r.Rows.Count 
    If r.Cells(n, 1) = r.Cells(n + 1, 1) Then 
        MsgBox "Duplicate data in " & r.Cells(n + 1, 1).Address 
    End If 
Next n
```

So it translates to `Range("myRange").Cells(n,1)`
and not

```
r(1, 1).Value
```

Comment: I normally comment only after testing the code. I kept my working sheet for a day only. I will have to do reworking on sample data, perhaps tomorrow. Pl bear till then.

Comment: @J St I have edited the Answer to address the concerns you raised yesterday. I hope if for  program whose you are the creator someone helps to achieve success of your creation, he at least deserves to be thanked by acknowledging his help and accepting answer with green tick mark.

Comment: @J St I would like to have feedback whether your problem is resolved or not. Acceptance of my answer is not important. It is only being sought as we may be wrong and you have come up with a better idea. Quest of learning is beyond age and experience.